# Query users in custom Azure roles from an MVC app

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I have defined custom roles in Azure in the application manifest as follows:

```
"allowedMemberTypes": [
  "User"
],
"displayName": "Admin",
"id": "81e10148-16a8-432a-b86d-ef620c3e48ef",
"isEnabled": true,
"description": "Admins can manage roles and perform all task actions.",
"value": "Admin"
```

From my MVC application, I would like to query the users found in these roles. With Graph API, I am able to see the custom roles attached to the application but I am unable to query the users attached to these roles. Is it possible with the graph api?
Thanks. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

We can get the roles which already assign to this application via the Azure Graph REST like below:

```
GET: https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}/servicePrincipals/{servicePrincipalid}/appRoleAssignedTo?api-version=1.6
Bearer {accessToken}
```

Then we can get the filter the result using the **id**( custom appRole id, eg.81e10148-16a8-432a-b86d-ef620c3e48ef) and **principalType**(User) to get the specific roles which assign to users.

More detail about entity and complex type of Azure Graph REST you can refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#serviceprincipal-entity).

Comment: Please consider accept the reply as answer if it resolve the issue so that other community who have the same issue could recognize the answer easily.